# How to properly enable mod_status on an apache server?

Tags: windows, apache, webserver, status, httpd.conf

I have been searching everywhere looking for how to properly enable mod_status and nothing has worked. My server is called "willserver.main.ca". I am running the server on a windows virtual machine.
I tried adding this to HTTPD config file:

```
<location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from main.ca

</location>
```

Any tips or help? I don't know if I am supposed to uncomment something or if I am just trying the wrong syntax over and over

Comment: My "<" were removed from my code when I commented. This is it though:<location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from trusys.ca

</location>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, first confirm that you have a `LoadModule` that looks similar to this:

```
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

If that isn't there, then you'll need to download and add it.

If it is there then try this:

```
<Location /server-status> 
    SetHandler server-status 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

See if you can then hit http://www.my-domain.com/server-status

If you can then switch it to:

```
<Location /server-status> 
    SetHandler server-status 
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.100
</Location>
```

Where `192.168.1.100` is your internal IP if accessing internally or your external IP. This will restrict it so not just anyone can access it. You can then add multiple `Allow from` for each IP / IP range that requires access.

Comment: @Welsh Three notes if you can update:
1. Order Allow,Deny should have no space between Allow and Deny.
2. If there are multiple virtual hosts, there should be a default virtual host configured without a ServerName set for mod_status to work properly.
3. Surround them with an <IfModule status_module>...</IfModule> to ease enabling and disabling the module

Answer (score 5):

Apache 2.4 do not appear to like a space in the Order directive.

Order Allow, Deny only works as

Order Allow,Deny

Comment: This is true. The `mod_access` documentation says _[Keywords may only be separated by a comma; no whitespace is allowed between them.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order)_

Answer (score 4):

mod_status built into Apache web server to get server status from a web browser. With this module we can easily find out how well the server is performing. All reports are generated in a html format.

Step1. Check if status module is enabled or not
apache2ctl -M   or ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Step2. If not enabled, enable it by the command,

sudo a2enmod status

step3. Configure access,

Open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf  and comment the lines,

```
        #<Location /server-status>
        #    SetHandler server-status
        #    Require local
        #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
        #</Location>
```

And add the following line,

```
        <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Location>
```

We can restrict the access of server status for particular IP’s in this configuration by editing ,
Allow from our_public_ipaddress   instead of    Allow from all

Save the status.conf  file .

Step4. Restart apache by the command,

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Step5. Check the server status page in browser

http://server-ip/server-status

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X Yosemite I had to use this otherwise some endless loop was happening:

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
   # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
   # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
   # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
   #
   <Location /server-status>
     SetHandler server-status
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Taken from https://osiutino.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/install-apache-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/

Answer (score 1):

Below config worked for me.

```
ExtendedStatus on
<Location /mod_status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Require local
</Location>
```